# Knockout Mapping: Object not Filled

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am learning Knockout and cannot get Knockout.mapping.fromJS to work. Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON("data/status.json", function(data) {
        var members = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
});
ko.applyBindings(members);
```

I am using a template. Here is the template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="membersTemplate">
    <li data-bind="text: members.dname"></li>
</script>
```

And the markup...

```
<div id="members">
<h2>Members</h2>
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'membersTemplate', foreach: members}"></ul>
</div>
```

The JSON data loads correctly, but the "members" object is "undefined." (Members.dname is one object property among many.)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than happy: **your `members` variable is outside of scope, so it gets lost after our AJAX call completes**. You want something either like this.

```
$.ajax({url:"/echo/json/", data:json, type:"POST", success:function(data) {
  var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
}});
```

So you apply the bindings inside of the scope of the AJAX call or something like this.

```
var self = this
self.members = ko.observableArray([]);
$.ajax({url:"/echo/json/", data:json, type:"POST", success:function(data) {
  var members = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
  self.members(members);
}});
// do the binding elsewhere
```

Which binds your response inside a closure. Remember that an AJAX call is a promise pattern, so you really don't know when the response is completed. Here's a [code](http://jsfiddle.net/jjperezaguinaga/4UaSP/) with a working example.